# Cascading Dropdown List Changing Extend Selection on The First Dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I want to create 3 Dropdown List for (Country, City and State) Cascading on Selection for The First Dropdown list Changing The Second and Selection for the second Changing The Third with **SQL Server (ADO.Net) and ASP.Net C#**!
and this error showing me
Can any one solve this error Please ?
Here the asp.net design code The Fist one..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6u5t.png)

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged">  
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select Location--</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The Second one:

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSecond" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="City"   
    DataValueField="City" AutoPostBack="True"   
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlSecond_SelectedIndexChanged">  
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select City--</asp:ListItem>  
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And The Third..

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlThird" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="State"   
    DataValueField="State">  
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select Area--</asp:ListItem>  
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

, the code of page load..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8L9K.png)

```java
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)

        {
            try
            {
                txtid.Text = (pr.Project.OrderByDescending(b => b.ProID).FirstOrDefault().ProID     
    +1).ToString();
            }
            catch
            {

                txtid.Text = "1";
            }
            btnadd.Visible = true;
            btndelete.Visible = false;
            btnupdate.Visible = false;
            GridView1.DataSource = pr.Project.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data     
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GROUP.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User     
    Instance=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Project", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            ddlFirst.DataSource = dt;
            ddlFirst.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

, code of dropdown lists with c#..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3t5g.png)

```java
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlSecond.Items.Clear();
        ddlSecond.Items.Add("Select State");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data     
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GROUP.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User     
    Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [City] from Project where Location=" +     
    ddlFirst.SelectedItem.Value, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        ddlSecond.DataSource = dt;
        ddlSecond.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlSecond_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlSecond.Items.Clear();
        ddlSecond.Items.Add("Select State");

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data 
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\GROUP.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User 
    Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [State] from Project where City=" + 
    ddlSecond.SelectedItem.Value, con);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        ddlSecond.DataSource = dt;
        ddlSecond.DataBind();
    }
```

and < **The Error** >..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoty.png)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.
```

Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

```
CS1061: 'ASP.webusercontrol_project_wuc_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webusercontrol_project_wuc_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Source Error:

```
Line 94: 
Line 95: 
Line 96:             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
Line 97:                     onselectedindexchanged="ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged">  
Line 98:                     <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select Location--</asp:ListItem>


Source File: g:\Projects\Admin-WebApp-Final-Version\WebUserControl\Project-WUC.ascx    Line: 96
```

I tried to create it with javascript only and it didn't work, and I tried to create it without a database and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The error message...

> CS1061: 'ASP.webusercontrol_project_wuc_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webusercontrol_project_wuc_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

... is a slightly long-winded way of telling you that you're trying to call a method called `ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged` but the compiler couldn't find a method which meets that description.

From the name of the method that the compiler is looking for, I guess it's probably intended to be an event handler for the user changing the selection in the first drop-down list, so let's check that...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged">  
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select Location--</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Yep, this is what is causing the compiler to look for a method with that name, so let's see what the event handler method is actually called.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

And there's the answer - the event handler is called `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`, not `ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged`. Renaming the method to `ddlFirst_SelectedIndexChanged` should make the compiler error go away.

As an aside, concatenating user input into a SQL statement like this...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [City] from Project where Location=" +     
    ddlFirst.SelectedItem.Value, con);
```

... isn't a great idea, because it's vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks, which a malicious user could use to do serious damage to your database](https://bobby-tables.com/). Using stored procedures, or an object relational mapper such as Entity Framework, is a much safer way of implementing your data access.

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameter's, you find this code quite a bit easier.

Say this markup:

```
<div style="float:left">
<h4>Region</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRegion" runat="server"
        DataTextField="Region"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>Country</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCountry" runat="server" Width="250px"
        DataTextField="Country" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>State</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboState" runat="server" Width="200px"
        DataTextField="state" 
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboState_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
<h4>City</h4>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCity" runat="server" Width="220"
        DataTextField="city"
        dataValueField="ID"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboCity_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Note how I "avoided" using the item list in the drop down boxes. The reason is if you re-fill, then you will have difficulty in clearing out the drop boxes.

And now our code is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        LoadData();
}


void LoadData()
{
    // load up first cbo box, region

    SqlCommand cmdSQL =
        new SqlCommand("SELECT region from vRegion ORDER BY region");

    cboRegion.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
    cboRegion.DataBind();
    cboRegion.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Region", ""));
}


protected void cboRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboRegion.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT Country FROM vCountryRegion
            WHERE region = @region
            ORDER BY Country";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboRegion.Text;
        cboCountry.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboCountry.DataBind();
        cboCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Country", ""));

    }
}

protected void cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboCountry.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT state from vCountryStates
            WHERE Country = @Country
            ORDER BY state";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCountry.Text;
        cboState.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboState.DataBind();
        cboState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select State", ""));

    }

}

protected void cboState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboState.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT id, city from vCities
            WHERE Country_name = @Country
            AND state_name = @State
            ORDER BY city";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCountry.Text;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboState.Text;

        cboCity.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboCity.DataBind();
        cboCity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select City", ""));
    }
}
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

And in the above, I also had this little routine (no need to type over and over the code to build a connection and load the data).

```
DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Countries))
    {
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```